# Are In-App Payments on Android with Intel XDK possible?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I've been searching for some time, but I could only find information about iOs In-App payments. Is it actually possible for Android too? Are there any workarounds?

If it is not possible on Android, can you recommend me another Hybrid App IDE, that supports In-App Payments on both iOs and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably simply need to look for the correct search term.

Instead of "in-app purchases", I looked for "in-app billing" and I found [IAP in the Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/article/iap-in-intel-xdk?language=en).  I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Well I tried both "purchases" and "payments", but both just returned iOs results. So I thought it wouldn't make much sense to name the Android one different. Thank you!

Comment: For a wider range of solutions, search for "cordova in-app billing" -- since the XDK is just a tool for creating Cordova apps.